# Logout of all devices, NodeJS and Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I'm developing an application, the NodeJs (along with Express) will be server side which will provide RESTful service and Angular 6 will utilize the RESTful API.

Now the problem is when a user change the password, then how to logout the user from all devices.

I'm using JWT for authentication.

Comment: What do you mean by all devices? Do you log user in mobile, desktop... or multiple devices?

Comment: How do you store login tokens? If it's in the database, you should remove all tokens from this user after the user has changed his password

Comment: Currently, the NodeJS return a JWT Token, which I save in the localStorage, I don't know whats the best practice

Comment: @Variable If i store the token in database, then should I have to check it (perform database query) at each request, which is a costly job

Comment: As per my remarks on your now-deleted question, readers will generally encourage new community members to write as detailed a question as they can muster. This question seems to suffer from the same problem - it was too brief, it didn't show the code that was causing the problem, and it was not well received as a result.

Comment: Note that it really is possible to get a good reception here - you just need to convince readers that you have made a solid personal effort first. I appreciate that is different from other places on the web where you might have received help previously, but the reason why people want to come here is the high quality standards enforced by the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long of search I have found one solution,

You should have an ***updated_at*** field in user table which stores the time user last updated his/her details,
You have to use this field as Encryption String for JWT, so when the user updates info, the tokens previously issued are considered as invalid so user wouldn't be able to perform any action with that, and he/she must have renew the token

Answer (score -1):

It is bad practise to logout the user when it changes password unless user voluntarily opts to logout from all the devices:-

Once the user logout , then clears localstorage and redirect to login as:-

Just change the authorization token when user updates the password and check that token is still valid for each request. If not valid, gives 401 error and then redirect to login page.

```
logout(){
/* clear your localStorage token /*
// redirect to login page 
}
```

### interceptor.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            // add authorization header with jwt token if available
            let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: { 
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                    }
                });
            }

            return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          // redirect to the login route
          // or show a modal showing, we are redirecting to you login page.
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Refer Link:- https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your response, but let me discuss a 'use case'
- A user login in multiple places (chrome, safari, mozilla), he then changes the password in chrome,
Now the tokens in safari and mozilla should be no longer accepted, how to handle this

Comment: What is 'use case' ?

Comment: So, what interceptor is doing here, it is using Authorization token with each and every request. Thus, in backend if there is something handled to check requested Authorization taken i.e.  if Authorization token not matches then it will send 401 error . This works even if browser is refreshed. Thus , in other devices if browser is refreshed, then it will give 401 error.

Comment: You can even have a look at socket.io. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814330/authentication-in-socket-io